# Docker Compose Postgres can't login but can via CLI

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Learning about Docker (4.11.1) compose and I'm having a weird issue with my Postgres DB.  It's a brand new installation so I've deleting and recreated on the latest version as well as alpine the issue persists. I assume I'm doing something wrong so I would like some help

What does work (not using docker compose):

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=myuser -d postgres

root@b2fc89a75d71:/# psql -U myuser
psql (14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

myuser=# exit
```

What kind of works (using Docker Compose):

```
version: '3.9'
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        
root@0ed9caa9c68f:/# psql -U postgres
psql (14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.
        
postgres=# exit
```

I say kind for the above because the postgres user works but it's not what I want.  Clearly it's not going to work as I want because I'm not setting a user but I wanted to show a working example without the user command and it certainly is working as expected.  The next example is where I'm scratching my head unsure of what's going on...

What DOES NOT WORK (using Docker Compose):

```
version: '3.9'
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
    
# Error 
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "myuser" does not exist
```

In regards to the environment variable syntax, I have tried the following and both still give the exact same results:

```
environment:
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  - POSTGRES_USER=myuser


OR

environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  POSTGRES_USER: myuser
```

Docker Logs in both cases working and not working (same):

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
syncing data to disk ... ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2022-08-24 04:46:06.058 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-08-24 04:46:06.060 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-24 04:46:06.086 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-24 04:46:03 UTC
2022-08-24 04:46:06.122 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down...2022-08-24 04:46:06.480 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2022-08-24 04:46:06.483 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-08-24 04:46:06.485 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
2022-08-24 04:46:06.487 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
2022-08-24 04:46:06.544 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2022-08-24 04:46:06.634 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-08-24 04:46:06.634 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-24 04:46:06.634 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-24 04:46:06.639 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-24 04:46:06.669 UTC [61] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-24 04:46:06 UTC
2022-08-24 04:46:06.699 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It seems that by adding the POSTGRES_USER command, there is something that not executing to create the user "myuser".  I'm hoping that I'm doing something wrong or have a glaring typo, or missed something obvious in the docs, that I can't seem to find.  Any and all help is much appreciated.  Thank you,

P.S. Just wanted to add the oddly enough, this is purely a Database Login issue, this issue is not in any way affecting my application which is really weird.  The app/database connection works just as expected, just can't login locally to the database from within container.

Comment: What the logs show? `sudo docker logs <your_container_id>`

Comment: If you didn't destroy your container after the first docker-compose, then the 2nd one just starts that up again and doesn't recreate the database.

Comment: I have tried docker compose down, as well as completely removing the base image and still the same issue.  Something about adding a user seems to break getting local access to the database for me...